# rviz on jetson tk1 board

Tags: ros, rviz, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all! I am having a problem getting rviz to work in my jetson tk1. I am getting the following error when I roslaunch the .launch file that we use:

[rviz_desktop-2] process has died [pid 11126, exit code -7, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rqt_rviz/rqt_rviz -d /home/ubuntu/enterprise_ws/src/mst_control/vcg/Enterprise.rviz __name:=rviz_desktop __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/e81b465c-b94b-11e4-a101-00044b26fcd3/rviz_desktop-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/e81b465c-b94b-11e4-a101-00044b26fcd3/rviz_desktop-2*.log

And of course, rviz doesn't work. I've already done the following and added to my ~.bash.src file:

unset GTK_IM_MODULE

I had to do that for rviz to work just by starting roscore and ros running rviz. I can rosrun rviz, but for our purposes, launching it from the launch file is troublesome. mst_control and Enterprise are our packages and names, fyi. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203738/rviz-on-jetson-tk1-board/) by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running rviz on the TK1 is not recommended. You should have a separate machine for running visualization.

This looks like rviz is segfaulting. There are few things you can try to isolate the problem:

- Run your command by itself, instead of within a launch file. You'll get more descriptive error messages.
- You're using rqt_rviz instead of rviz. Try running your config file with rviz
- If both of those work, run rviz with the default config, and add the items from your config individually. If adding a particular display causes rviz to crash, then you know the problem is with that display.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow these steps,
in bashrc.

"unset GTK_IM_MODULE"

$ sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-robot-model

$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src

$ git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_model.git

$ cd ~/catkin_ws

$ catkin_make

$ source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [vishu2287](https://answers.ros.org/users/23634/vishu2287/) with karma: 46 on 2015-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1